# Azure WebApp URL rewrite not working for Laravel 5.2

Tags: azure, iis, url-rewriting, laravel-5, web-config

I have a Laravel 5.2 application running on an Azure Webapp. Everything works fine on the local environment. I uploaded from a local git repo, installed the vendor files with composer and loaded the home page, but this is all that works. When trying to visit any other url I get the following message:

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
>   changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I am unable to get url rewrite or custom error codes to work, its as if no settings are recognised but if there is an error in the web.config file it returns an error. I have placed the web.config file in the public folder and set this path in the settings on Azure. The web.config file I am currently using can be found here: https://gist.github.com/bobsta63/7d5d4af32491c11dafc4

What am I doing wrong?

Also is there a comprehensive tutorial on the web.config file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue.  Restarting the Azure web app fixed the problem.

The reason the problem occurs is because the IIS App Pool needs to be recycled in order to load a new or changed web.config file. Restarting the Azure web app is a way of achieving this.

Comment: Seems like I was using the restart feature in kudu. This time I went into the portal and restarted it and it worked.